# VSTS Hosted agents fails with: The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003121 which is not installed

Tags: azure-pipelines

My builds have been working on VSTS agents for some time and then I installed VS 2017 on my dev machine breaking my projects locally. Turns out that I didnt have a sdk element in global.json.

I added:

```
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003121"
  }
```

but this resulted in the build agents throwing the following error:

```
The project is configured to use .NET Core SDK version 1.0.0-preview2-003121 which is not installed or cannot be found under the path C:\Program Files\dotnet
```

I looked up that both 1.0 and 1.1 should be installed.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/hosted#software

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the 1.0 installed on VSTS agents actually is 1.0.1 sdk.
https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/blob/master/known-issues-vs2015.md#missing-sdk

so changing to

```
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
```

made the build succeeded again.

Comment: Do you guys have KPIs to get SO questions answered :) ?